# Unable to fill the height of TextBox in DockPanel

Tags: wpf, textbox, height

I am trying to fill the TextBox height for all remaining space in the DockPanel but no success. I have not even found a successful example code doing this stuff.

Here is what I have done:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <DockPanel Background="Red" LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
     <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Save" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10 5"/>
     <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"
        AcceptsTab="True"
        Margin="5 10"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Am I missing something?? I have also tried VerticalAlignment property to Stretch of TextBox, no success. Below is the output window.

[image]

Comment: Hi,Can you show me your whole XAML code.Because your code is working with my sample application.Somewhere it might be referring textbox style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,set your textbox style to NULL and check whether its working fine.

```
<DockPanel Background="Red" LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Save" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10 5"/>
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Margin="5 10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{x:Null}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Oh ... you caught the issue. It was in the style.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the textbox to autosize without having to mess with the Style you can simply set your height back to Double.NaN.  The xaml below is stripped to only show the relevant bits.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
  <TextBox Height="NaN"/>
</DockPanel>
```